# How long is unit cell in metre?

Tags: condensed-matter

I have been reading papers on amorphous and crystalline heterostructure (topic related to condensed matter and solid state physics). Frequently, they used unit cell (uc) to describe the thickness of their material. Since I have little background, I am not sure what is the actual length of unit cell.

So, as the title suggest, how long is one unit cell in metre?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A unit cell is simply the smallest sub component of crystalline structure, from which the entire lattice can be created. For instance, in a cubic lattice, the unit cell is a cube. Since the lattice spacing of a material depends highly on its constituents, the length of a unit cell is not a standard unit of measurement, but simply a way to demonstrate how large a crystal is, in reference to its lattice spacing.

I hope this helps!